# Change File upload size limit on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Nginx)

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to increase the current file upload size (2MB) limit on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

on uploading files greater than 2 MB I was getting error code 413 Request entity too large. To rectify this I created a file `custom.conf` at `\.platform\nginx\conf.d` and contents of file are :

`client_max_body_size 500M;`

and now on uploading files greater than 2 MB I am  getting error code 500 Internal Server Error

(p.s. i have also tried to place "custom.conf" at `\.ebextensions\nginx\conf.d` and "custom.config" at `\.ebextensions\` but it was of no use)

Comment: Have you inspected any EB logs to check what causes the internal error?